# using post request in urlib in python

Tags: python, networking, urllib2

I am trying to use post request in **https** website.But **urllib** work only on http.so can you tell me how to use urllib for https.
thanks in advance.

Comment: [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply not true that urllib only works on HTTP, not HTTPS. It fully supports HTTPS.

In any case though, you probably want to be using the third-party library [requests](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use httplib:

```
    import httplib
    import urllib
    params = urllib.urlencode({'user': 'pew', 'age': 52})
    headers = {"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",  "Accept": "text/plain"}
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("your_domain.com")
    conn.request("POST", "/form/handler/test", params, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print response.status
    print response.reason
    reply = response.read()
    print reply
```

Comment: do we need to install openssl for https in urllib

Comment: As far as I understand - yes.